# Can not install the application after compilation in Android Studio

Tags: android

In the android studio project, the field of some actions stopped running on the device, it seems that there are no errors when creating apk, but when installed on the device it gives an error "The application is not installed." What could be the reason? Possibly updated gradle and added a third-party library, but there are no errors when compiling apk-debbug

Comment: If it built, this is a device problem.  Try uplugging, rebooting the device, killing and restarting adb, uninstalling any old versions.  The usual steps.

Comment: I tried it on different devices and versions of android, but everywhere this error (

Comment: If anything, I have a problem solved by myself, I don `t know what it was but now everything is fine